# use return value from method in another method

Tags: c#, object, oop, return

I student for computer science first year,
we got task in c#
I have problem to use the return object from SearchTrip method , then in another method TripUpdate to go in this object and update him with new values how can I do it properly ?

```
 static Trip SearchTrip(Trip[] tArr, int tripnum)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < tArr.Length; i++)
        {
            if (tArr[i].GetTrip_num() == tripnum)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("the trip exists");
                return tArr[i];
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
    static void Trip_update(Trip[] tArr, int tripnum)
    {

        if (SearchTrip(tArr, tripnum) != null)
        {
            
            Console.WriteLine("enter trip number");
            int trip_num = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("enter destination");
            String destination = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("enter trip date and time in format: dd/mm/yy hh:mm:ss");
            DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(Console.ReadLine());


            for (int i = 0; i < tArr.Length; i++)
            {
                if (tArr[i].GetDt() == dt)
                { Console.WriteLine("EROR already have trip with this date"); }
                // update the trip that we got from SearchTrip method with new data;
                else {   }
            }
            
        }
    }
```

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow, in the current form, you haven't really asked a specific question

Comment: I finished all , I didn't post my assignment here. I want to use the return fro method SearchTrip . and I want to use this object in order to update him with new values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U dont need update value with new object, instead, if ur properties in Trip class are public, u can easy use

```
trip.trip_num = trip_num;
trip.destination = destination;
trip.dt = dt;
```

Or create method inside Trip class like

```
public void Update(trip_num, destination, dt){ // insert here ur types also
 this.trip_num = trip_num;
 this.destination = destination;
 this.dt = dt;
```

}

in this case u can do

```
trip.Update(trip_num,destination,dt);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 //assumming your trip object parameters (destination & date) are destination and 
  date:

static Trip SearchTrip(Trip[] tArr, int tripnum)
{

    for (int i = 0; i < tArr.Length; i++)
    {
        if (tArr[i].GetTrip_num() == tripnum)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("the trip exists");
            return tArr[i];
        }
    }
    return null;
}
static void Trip_update(Trip[] tArr, int tripnum)
{
  //added
  var trip = SearchTrip(tArr, tripnum);
    if ( trip != null)
    {
        
        Console.WriteLine("enter trip number");
        int trip_num = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("enter destination");
        String destination = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("enter trip date and time in format: dd/mm/yy hh:mm:ss");
        DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            if (trip.GetDt() == dt)
            { Console.WriteLine("EROR already have trip with this date"); }
            // update the trip that we got from SearchTrip method with new data;
            else { 
              trip.tripnum = trip_num;
              trip.destination = destination;
              trip.date = dt ;
            } 
    }
 }
```